# Python Discord.py - ctx is a required argument

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot, and I am following a simple tutorial, and I can't get the simplest command to work.
I am on python 3.6 and running discord.py version 0.16.12

```
    #Imports
import time
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

#Initialize
client = discord.Client()#Creates Client
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')#Sets prefix for commands(!Command)

#Code
@bot.command()
async def SendMessage(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello')
```

The code should work but it gives me the error `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.`

Answer (score 7):

Discord.py commands do not, by default, pass the context. You specify that you would like the context passed by saying so as an argument to the decorator.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def SendMessage(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello')
```

Comment: I tried your fix, but now it says 'Context' object has no attribute 'send'.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use the v1.0 tutorial (which has `Context.send` and also doesn't require `pass_context=True`) with a v0.* discord.py version. I suggest double-checking your discord.py version.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html):

> A command must always have at least one parameter, ctx, which is the
>   [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) as the first one.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy fix for this :

```
bot = discord.Client()#Creates Client
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')#Sets prefix for commands(!Command)
```

Just change client to bot that'll do.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't initialize `commands.Bot()` and `discord.Client()` at the same time. Just remove `client` variable and everything should work.

```
# Imports
import time
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

# Initialize
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

# Code
@bot.command()
async def SendMessage(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (choose your own prefix)

```
import time
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')
            
@client.command()
async def SendMessage(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

The reason your getting this is because you need to define `ctx`.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

@client.command()
async def Konnichiwa(ctx):
await ctx.send("Konnichiwa, my Tomodachi!")

Comment: please use proper indentation and formatting